# Best method to server-side img compress from full src img

Tags: php

I want to display a simple image gallery on a PHP webpage where the images are compressed; however, it allows for full res jpegs to be downloaded. And I'm just curious what method you would recommend for a project like this?

I'm thinking I store the full-res jpeg on my server and use server-side PHP `imagecreatefromjpeg() and imagejpeg()` to create a lower-res thumbnail of the image with an option to download? Or I suppose I could store lower res and high res jpegs both on the server and just echo them out but I would rather not store the lower res if possible.

Are there any other options for a project like this? And if imagejepg() is a good option, would someone direct me in how to use it?

Comment: "Best" is subjective. Re-compressing the images every time will eat CPU (which you may or may not notice) while saving disk space, while compressing only once and storing will eat disk but save CPU. You really just need to weigh these options. I personally would almost always lean towards creating them just once.

Comment: You should create separate images of the sizes you need. If you keep generating the low-res images using `imagecreatefromjpeg()`etc on the fly, it will quickly result in performance issues if you get many requests simultaneously

Comment: You might want to look into some library like [league/glide](https://glide.thephpleague.com/).

Comment: why this question was tagged with mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Lower-rez images typically take much less disk space, much less, than hi-rez images. Disk space is extremely unlikely to be a limiting factor when you pre-create the smaller images.

And, resizing and decompressing on the fly in response to user requests eats server power. Store the low-rez images: think green.

For what it's worth, WordPress (40% of web servers on the net) resizes on upload and stores resized images, so that approach is proven effective.